# Set Listview column header icons on right side vb6

Tags: listview, vb6

Could somebody please tell me, Is it possible to set the column header icon to the right side of the list view column header (text on the left side and icon on right side) in vb6?

Answer (score 1):

I found it :)

```
With lvwBookmarks
    Set .ColumnHeaderIcons = Me.ImageList1
    With .ColumnHeaders
        .Clear
        .Add 1, "Column1", "Sequence", 1300, , 1
        .Add 2, "Column2", "Name", 2000, , 0
        .Add 3, "Column3", "Text", 7000, , 0
    End With

    .ColumnHeaders(1).IconOnRight = True
    .ColumnHeaders(2).IconOnRight = True
    .ColumnHeaders(3).IconOnRight = True

End with
```